# How to Add LinearLayout and its child contents Inside Parent LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

When I tried to add `LinearLayout` at runtime in Android, the views and layout of which I'm adding is not showing.

Issue is when i add TextView to ParentLinearLayout it is displaying. But if i add to childLinearLayout and while childlayout added to parentlayout at that time it is not showing anything.

I have `ParentLinearLayout` which is designed in xml now i need to child `LinearLayout` from java code along with its contents.

**Structure:**

- ParentLinearLayout(Defined in Xml)

  - Child LinearLayout(Get from Code)

    - TextView
    - Button

**Java code:**

```
    LinearLayout ParentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    LinearLayout childLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    childLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));
    childLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0F0"));
    childLayout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    //defined in Xml
    ParentLayout.addView(childLayout);

    TextView textView1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textView1.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
    textView1.setText("Offers");
    textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    textView1.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 10); // in pixels (left, top, right, bottom)

    Button btnAB= new Button(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40,40); //width:40dp and height:40dp
    btnAB.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
    final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        btnAB.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon) );
    } else {
        btnAB.setBackground( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
    }
    btnAB.setClickable(false);

    childLayout.addView(textView1);
    childLayout.addView(btnAB);
```

**Xml:**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <!-- Here I need to add one linear layout and inside of it TextView and Button -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the XML also.

Comment: But, what the problem actually?

Comment: When i add those views its not displaying in parentLayout @ssh

Comment: Where is the element with the id `@+id/search_discover` that you have used in your `HorizontalScrollView`?

Comment: I didnt copy the full code it is align to search_discover button, problem is while adding layout to parentlayout. If i add textview to parentlayout at that time its displaying view. @PrerakSola

Comment: I tested your code and it's working fine. Add the complete HEX value of the background color for `childLayout`. You have entered a 3 digit color. Make it 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
    LinearLayout ParentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

LinearLayout childLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
childLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));
childLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0F0"));
childLayout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
//defined in Xml
ParentLayout.addView(childLayout);


TextView textView1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textView1.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
textView1.setText("Offers");
textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
textView1.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 10); // in pixels (left, top, right, bottom)

Button btnAB= new Button(MainActivity.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40,40); //width:40dp and height:40dp
btnAB.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    btnAB.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon) );
} else {
    btnAB.setBackground( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
}
btnAB.setClickable(false);
childLayout.removeAllViews();
childLayout.addView(textView1);
childLayout.addView(btnAB);
```